# Select and mark part of text in android

Tags: java, android

i want to select some part of the text from text view using long press and drag. Basically am looking for a functionality like android pdf reader text selection. how can i implement this? after select some text i need to highlight it (color change/underline etc) .When i again visit the same page, app should show the content like i previously highlighted.

I saw `the textview.setTextIsSelectable(true)` option, 
when i use this i can select the text, whats next? is this the proper method for this kind of task ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
textView.setSelection(startIndex, endIndex);
```

instead